# Error On Sending Email

Tags: php, email

A few days ago, i can send email via **mail()** function on my server. But now, mails doens't sending . There isn't anything at error log. I don't get any error. I don't know, why emails not sending.

What can i do? How can i solve this?

**EDIT**
Now i get all emails (about 18 mails :) ) . Why mails delayed?

Comment: Is error reporting on? `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: yes. And there isn't any error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's mailer function does not actually deliver the mail. It simply hands it off to an SMTP server for that. Whether or not it actually gets delivered is not considered by `mail()`, it's just concerned with the hand-off.

If the SMTP server accepts it, then `mail()` will return true and pretend everything worked fine. The SMTP server may delete the mail, send it to the wrong place, route it through a tangle of other SMTP servers causing the mail to be delayed by a year, etc..., but `mail()` will still have said everything's fine.

The place to look for the cause of this is your mail server's own log. If there was a delivery problem, there'd be a list of each delivery attempt in there somewhere.

Comment: but sometimes mail delivering at the moment, sometimes delivering with delayed. And mail() returning TRUE.

Comment: Exactly. As long as the local SMTP server accepts the mail, `mail()` will return true. But the actual email itself can sit in a queue for days or weeks until the SMTP server gets around to delivering it. So, look at the SMTP server's logs. That's where you'll see why there's a delay. maybe the receiving end is using grey-listing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing [this](http://www.dotvoid.com/2007/04/problem-sending-mail-with-php-mail-function/)?

> The problem seems to be that PHP use
>   the ini directive sendmail_from to set
>   the from email address in the SMTP
>   protocol. If this is not correctly
>   set, or if it does not match the from
>   header in the email headers, the email
>   is caught by spam protection software.
>   The simplest solution is to set the
>   directive during execution:
>
> ini_set("sendmail_from", $email_from);
>
> $headers = "From: $email_from";
>
> mail($to, $subject, $message,
>   $headers);

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now i have got 18 mails together. I don't know, why mails are delaying.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your receiving mailserver implemented greylisting (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting) ...

Do you have access to the mailqueue or maillog of your webserver? In that case you can search for delayed or bounced messages there.

Comment: I can login to plesk panel of my reseller. But i don't know where is maillog.

Comment: sorry, i do not know if a non-admin plesk user can access the mailqueue (think not)